# Can we omit the table name in hibernate config xml for class storing result of join query?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

In hibernate mapping xml the `<class>` elements are used to define specific mappings from a Java classes to the database tables. The Java class name is specified using the name attribute of the class element and the database table name is specified using the table attribute.

So can i omit this tablename somehow while using named query which joins multiple table?Executing the code without the table name throws some exception.

Named query result will be stored in that class and in the mapping xml the class name needs to be mapped with a table name.

```
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="Employee" table="EMPLOYEE">
```